# Is there a way where i can remove trailing 1's at the end of a string as shown below

Tags: python

I have a list format as shown below.

```
stripped_list=['WLH1', 'GWJ1', 'AV11', 'UBN1']
```

I want to remove trailing 1's at the end but if i am using below code

```
stripped_list2 = [[item.replace('1', '') for item in z] for z in stripped_list]
```

it is stripping AV11 to AV only but i need AV1.

How to solve this?

I have a list format as shown below.

```
stripped_list=['WLH1', 'GWJ1', 'AV11', 'UBN1']
```

I want to remove trailing 1's at the end but if i am using below code

```
stripped_list2 = [[item.replace('1', '') for item in z] for z in stripped_list]
```

it is stripping AV11 to AV only but i need AV1.

How to solve this?

Comment: Is the 1 always going to be at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.sub` with `$` for match end of string for replace last `1`:

```
import re

stripped_list=['WLH1', 'GWJ1', 'AV11', 'UBN1']

stripped_list2 = [re.sub( r'1$', '', z) for z in stripped_list]

print (stripped_list2)

['WLH', 'GWJ', 'AV1', 'UBN']
```

If need remove all last values:

```
stripped_list2 = [z[:-1] for z in stripped_list]

print (stripped_list2)

['WLH', 'GWJ', 'AV1', 'UBN']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension, assuming `1` may or not may not be present as the last character and then removing it if its there -

```
stripped_list=['WLH1', 'GWJ1', 'AV11', 'UBN1']
print([item[:-1] if item[-1]=='1' else item for item in stripped_list])
```

**Output:**

```
['WLH', 'GWJ', 'AV1', 'UBN']
```

Answer (score 0):

`#assuming 1 is always at the end:`

```
stripped_list=['WLH1', 'GWJ1', 'AV11', 'UBN1']

for i, word in enumerate(stripped_list): #iterate over the list using enumerate to get the index and value 
    stripped_list[i] = word[:-1] #change the word in the list to its slice which doesn't contain the 1 at the end 
    
print(stripped_list)
```

`#assuming 1 is not always at the end:`

```
stripped_list=['WLH1', 'GWJ1', 'AV11', 'UBN1']

for i, word in enumerate(stripped_list): #iterate over the list using enumerate to get the index and value
    if word[:-1] == '1': #test if the last character is '1'
       stripped_list[i] = word[:-1]#change the word in the list to its slice which doesn't contain the 1 at the end 
    
print(stripped_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the data until the last element of the list.

```
s = [i[:len(stripped_list)-1] for i in stripped_list]
```

Output:

```
['WLH', 'GWJ', 'AV1', 'UBN']
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I added an explanation.